# Flutter - Getting the name of TopView in Flutter Navigation Stack

Tags: flutter, navigation

How to know if a view is present(showing) in the Flutter Navigation

Is there any way to do it? Checked the flutter `Navigator` class but couldn't figure out anything. Attaching a Screenshot below. [image]

Comment: "View is present" means?

Comment: I mean a view is showing @ChiragBargoojar

Comment: You can use `visibility_detector` package https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector and wrap your `Dialog()` with `VisibilityDetector()` it fires a callback when the widget's visibility changes.

Comment: I'll try now and let you know if it could solve my bug for a specific use case.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar This VisibilityDetector requires a flutter upgrade, I can't do that right now due to some dependency like flutter version in circle ci etc. Any other idea?